# how to retain current active tab on page reload in bootstrap 4.5.2

Tags: reactjs, tabs

We are using the bootstrap 4.5.2 for css in our reactjs app.
Is there anyway we can retain the tab selection after the browser refresh
If it is in account2, after browser refresh's it still goes to account1.
We are not using react-bootstrap library, we are using the bootstrap css library installed using npm.

```
 <div className="nav nav-tabs" id="accountTab" role="tablist">
                 <a className="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-home" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-home" aria-selected="true" onClick={() => handleTabClick('account1')}   >account1 &nbsp;<span className="badge badge-pill badge-dark">{dataCount && dataCount.account1}</span></a> 
                <a className="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false" onClick={() => handleTabClick('account2')}   >account2 &nbsp;<span className="badge badge-pill badge-dark">{dataCount && dataCount.account2}</span>   </a>
                <a className="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false" onClick={() => handleTabClick('account3')}   >account3 &nbsp;<span className="badge badge-pill badge-dark">{dataCount && dataCount.account3}</span>   </a>
                <a className="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-contact" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-contact" aria-selected="false" onClick={() => handleTabClick('account4')}   >Others &nbsp;<span className="badge badge-pill badge-dark">{0}</span>   </a>
            </div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below if the fix I tried and it works for me with out any issues, anybody has any better suggestions please let me know

```
var activeTabCss = "nav-item nav-link active";
var tabCss = "nav-item nav-link";
```

const account = useSelector(state=>state.shipment.courier);

handleTabClick('account1')}   >account1  {dataCount && dataCount.account1} 
 handleTabClick('account2')}   >account2  {dataCount && dataCount.account2}   
 handleTabClick('account3')}   >account3  {dataCount && dataCount.account3}   
 handleTabClick('account4')}   >Others  {0}